# Несанкционированный возврат средств за In-App покупку в Android

Tags: android, google-play, playmarket, android-billing, in-app

Недавно выпустил [игру](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thedivergenceofthecurliszero.android.geometrywars) на Android с In-App покупкой, которую реализовал так, как написано [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/444072/). Было совершено несколько покупок, деньги были возвращены пользователям без моего участия за все из них. Знакомые говорили, что деньги возвращались им сами, они ничего специально не делали.

Я завел новый Google аккаунт, установил игру из Play Маркет, сделал покупку и больше приложение не открывал. Спустя три дня деньги вернулись мне в полном объеме. [image: история заказа, совершенного мной]

Похожая ситуация была у каждой покупки: спустя **ровно 72 часа** после оплаты был инициирован возврат средств **в каждом случае**.

В [справке](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2741495?hl=ru&ref_topic=7281225) Play Console говорится о трех причинах возврата средств:

1. Пользователь вернул платное приложение.
2. Пользователь запросил возврат средств.
3. Несанкционированные или случайные покупки.

Последний пункт мне не очень ясен, но первые два отметаются сразу: по крайней мере я никаких запросов на возврат не делал.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой или знает ее причину?

Некоторые сведения:

- Игра залита меньше месяца назад, ~250 скачиваний.
- Покупки совершались с территории России и Украины.
- Аккаунт продавца создан, год назад выпустил платное приложение, деньги за него перечисляются исправно.
- Хоть я и залил игру сразу в рабочую версию, у нее до сих пор висит подпись (Бета-версия), почему - для меня пока загадка, быть может потому что в описании у меня есть фраза про Бета-версию игры.
- Игра сделана полностью в Android Studio.
- зависимость в build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.0'
```

Comment: Я бы старался обходить покупки внутри приложения и платные приложения. Гугл плей очень жадно забирает проценты. Нужно искать лазейки и делать покупки напрямую... Лично я не разу не встречал проблем..

Comment: @Ilnar, ладно бы процент, у них тех. поддержка ужасная и баны от ботов за нарушения, которые сами же боты и сделали. Ну и ещё монополизм) Однако сами покупки сложно в обход делать. Да ещё это и запрещено правилами магазина.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Монополизм это зло)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего вы не сделали подтверждение покупки. Это требуется для покупок, которые не являются `consumable`. Смотрите документацию на этот счёт тут: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate. Там сказано, правда, что подтвержение покупки требуется для версии библиотеки покупок >=2.

Вам надо дополнить вопрос кодом, в т.ч. скрипта сборки, чтобы показать какие у вас версии библиотек. И рассказать какие типы покупок используются.

Comment: Похоже, что так и есть, использую 3ю версию библиотеки, и в документации как раз сказано про возврат через 72 часа, все сходится. Если я правильно понял, для подтверждения покупки необходим вызов billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, consumeResponseListener);

Comment: вызов billingClient.consumeAsync нужен если у вас вашу покупку можно несколько раз делать. Например покупка внутриигровой валюты. Если это одноразовая покупка, например отключение рекламы навсегда, то надо вызывать метод aknowledge.

Comment: Точно, спасибо! Тема этих методов уже [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56585626/how-to-acknowledge-in-app-purchases-in-android) поднималась.